# How to do remote code coverage with PyCharm?

Tags: python, code-coverage, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have the professional edition of Pycharm 4.0.4. I am running the IDE on Windows and remotely debugging a Python script on a Linux machine. I would like to see what sort of code coverage I am getting. How do I do that?

I am relatively new to Python programming and haven't tried code coverage of a local script, so apologies if I am asking to wrong question. Also, I am not using Vagrant.

Many Thanks, Dan